# Removing extra chapter numbering in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters, books, count

I'm using different chapter names in the chapter itself and the table of contents: `\chapter[Chapter 1 – Introduction]{Introduction}`. I'm also using chapter numbers (`\thechapter`) in chapter headers as per [this recommendation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555644/).

There seems to be a conflict with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` because the ToC still adds extra chapter numbers:

[image: Extra chapter numbers in table of content]

How would I get rid of those extra chapter numbers (e.g. ***1*** Chapter 1 – Introduction)?

I'm starting to use a lot of custom codes. Here's what it looks like (sorry for the long list of packages):

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,hidelinks]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.2in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\urlstyle{rm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xurl}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,columns=2,intoc=false,options={-s index-style.ist}]
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{tocloft}


% Chapter Headers

\regtotcounter{chapter}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\raggedright\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{62}{56}\selectfont}
  {\LARGE\rmfamily\mdseries
   % magic number 25pt
   \raisebox{25pt}{\smash{\parbox[t]{4em}{\thechapter\\/\\26}}}}
  {0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}[140pt]

% Title Sizes

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{140pt} % Redundant but needed

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\fontsize{22}{24}\selectfont}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{17pt}{20pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\fontsize{22}{28}\selectfont}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{20pt}{20pt}

% Table of Contents Config

\newcount\cnta
\cftsetpnumwidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont {\ttfamily\global\cnta}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum {%
  \makebox[0pt][l]%
     {\kern-\dimexpr\linewidth\relax\makebox[2em][l]{\ttfamily\normalsize\the\cnta}}%
}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\ttfamily\global\cnta}
\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum {%
  \makebox[0pt][l]%
     {\kern-\dimexpr\linewidth\relax\makebox[2em][l]{\ttfamily\large\the\cnta}}%
\vskip14pt
}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\ttfamily\bfseries\global\cnta}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum {%
  \makebox[0pt][l]%
     {\kern-\dimexpr\linewidth\relax\makebox[2em][l]{\large\bfseries\the\cnta}}%
\vskip7pt
}

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\ttfamily\large} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\rmfamily\large\bfseries}

\setlength{\cftpartindent}{4em}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{4em}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{4em}

\begin{document}

% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents{}

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Inception}
\chapter[Chapter 1 – Introduction]{Introduction}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}

\chapter[Chapter 2 – Middle]{Middle}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}

\chapter[Chapter 3 – Middle]{Conclusion}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change redefinition of `\ctfchapfont` from

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\rmfamily\large\bfseries}
```

to

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\rmfamily\large\bfseries\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}}
```

That means, (locally) redefine `\numberline` for every chapter toc entry, hence the chapter number is hidden from typesetting.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{tocloft}


% Chapter Headers

\regtotcounter{chapter}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\raggedright\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{62}{56}\selectfont}
  {\LARGE\rmfamily\mdseries
   % magic number 25pt
   \raisebox{25pt}{\smash{\parbox[t]{4em}{\thechapter\\/\\26}}}}
  {0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}[140pt]

% Title Sizes

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{140pt} % Redundant but needed

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\fontsize{22}{24}\selectfont}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{17pt}{20pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
  {\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\fontsize{22}{28}\selectfont}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{20pt}{20pt}

% Table of Contents Config

\newcount\cnta
\cftsetpnumwidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont {\ttfamily\global\cnta}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum {%
  \makebox[0pt][l]%
     {\kern-\dimexpr\linewidth\relax\makebox[2em][l]{\ttfamily\normalsize\the\cnta}}%
}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\ttfamily\global\cnta}
\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum {%
  \makebox[0pt][l]%
     {\kern-\dimexpr\linewidth\relax\makebox[2em][l]{\ttfamily\large\the\cnta}}%
\vskip14pt
}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\ttfamily\bfseries\global\cnta}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum {%
  \makebox[0pt][l]%
     {\kern-\dimexpr\linewidth\relax\makebox[2em][l]{\large\bfseries\the\cnta}}%
\vskip7pt
}

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\ttfamily\large} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\rmfamily\large\bfseries\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}}

\setlength{\cftpartindent}{4em}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{4em}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{4em}

\begin{document}

% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Inception}
\chapter[Chapter 1 – Introduction]{Introduction}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}

\chapter[Chapter 2 – Middle]{Middle}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}

\chapter[Chapter 3 – Middle]{Conclusion}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but chapter numbers then disappear in the chapters themselves. It doesn't seem to like this: 

```\regtotcounter{chapter}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\raggedright\rmfamily\bfseries\fontsize{62}{56}\selectfont}
  {\LARGE\rmfamily\mdseries
   % magic number 25pt
   \raisebox{25pt}{\smash{\parbox[t]{4em}{\thechapter\\/\\26}}}}
  {0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}[140pt]```

Comment: @egarbugli Hi, I updated my answer. Hope it helps you this time.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the **Chapter 1 - ** to the ToC yourself.

The `\chapter` macro takes one optional and one required argument. These are:

`\chapter[`*toc+header title*`]{`*title*`}`

so your `\chapter[Chapter 1 - Introduction]{Introduction}` puts **Chapter 1 - Introduction** into the ToC and header, plus the chapter number and puts **Chapter 1** followed on another line by **Introduction** in the body of the document.

So, don't use the optional argument.

However, if you need different entries in the ToC, header, and document the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) provides two optional arguments for `\chapter` and other division headings as:

`\chapter[`*toc-title*`][`*header-title*`]{`*title*`}`